# single sign on with gmail using php

Tags: php

I will have username and password of gmail
          I want to develop an application in which i have an login in my site.When i do login in my site . I must get automatically login into gmail.There must be a link when the user clicks on the link he must be automatically get login into the site.
I will demostrate it with am example

Username:XXXXX
Password:XXXXX

Click here to go to gmail

It will be something like above on my Website.When user enters the Username and password And gets login and if he clicks on the link.He must be able to see his gmail account.I meam to say he must be login to gmail..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Federated Login for Google Account Users](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html).

Comment: I want to implement it in PHP?Is it possible..Any demo example to begin

Comment: It's a network thingy. PHP can create, read from and write to network connections. So yes, it is possible. On the other hand, there are already OpenID implementations available for PHP, so you do not need to concern yourself with the low level stuff. I am sure Google will help you to find OpenID implementations and examples in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can either us Google's OpenID or SAML2.0 implementations.

Have a look at [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/). It's a SAML/SAML2.0 implementation in PHP. We use it for our single sign on implementation. It has some documentation on how to integrate with Google. However it's not a single library, it's the basis for an application. You may be able to strip it back the components you need. It could be over kill depending on how far you want to take you single sign on solution.

Answer (score 1):

See Using OAuth for Login for google accounts - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login